# Listview animated component open detail view

Tags: android, listview

I want to show my list-view and detail view like in "Mashable" application below link
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mashable.android.phoenix
when click on list-view, detail-view show and on scroll and stretch detail-view, list-view item again instead of going back.
please install application on android device and check this component.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this talk from Google I/O '13. They show an example of transition between activities (which is what you are looking for if I understood correctly): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihzZrS69i_s